# swing gui jframe in netbeans autogenerated code problem

Tags: java

i am using netbeans 11.1.when i create a jframe and pick and drop components on jfarme.in the source code all the components are declared and initialized
inside the initComponent method.thus these are not accessable in the class.
any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some code, photo, or anything that allows to reproduce the problem.. you may also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: following is the auto generated code  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.JButton add = new javax.swing.JButton();
        javax.swing.JButton search = new javax.swing.JButton();
        javax.swing.JButton delete = new javax.swing.JButton();
        javax.swing.JTextField name = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        javax.swing.JTextField address = new javax.swing.JTextField();

Comment: so i cannot access to use these components in the class.